# Can I find out how many pages each separate computer has printed on our network printer?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

We have a network printer that 4 different people print from. Is there any way to see how many pages each individual computer has printed in a set timeframe? I know how to check the overall page count but I was curious about who's using the printer the most.

I thought maybe there might be some way to print out (or save as an Excel/csv file) a log of the pages printed and which IP addresses printed them but I haven't found anything yet. Also, the printer we're using is a Ricoh MP402. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a print server?

Comment: Instructions from your printer should be similar to this [Ricoh support page for MP C401](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001050/0001050898/view/security/int/0173.htm)

Comment: We aren't using a print server. It looks like davidmneedham's suggestion worked though. I was able to download a csv file of the print logs and now I just need to match up the IP addresses with the computers. Thanks!